# Scaling/Size reduction large longtable to pdflscape

Tags: longtable, tabularx, boxes, landscape, adjustbox

[image: Compiling]

I have an overly large table converted with excel2latex. It may span several pages, but currently, it stretches far beyond the margins of my landscape, despite the columns under “Evaluation metrics” and “Thematic clusters” (they could be less wide, but I don’t manage to change their width). Is it possible to use adjustbox or other scaling methods to fit the table on a page? I already had a look at numerous proposed solutions found on the forum, but couldn’t bring any of them to work in my case.
I’m adding the first few rows of the table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=openany,numbers=noenddot,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm,marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon,font={footnotesize,sf},labelfont={footnotesize,sf}]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{cont}{#1~#2\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelsep=period,labelformat=cont}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
                \tiny
                \singlespacing
%               \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%               \setlength\LTright{0pt}
                \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
                % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table_1'
                \begin{longtable}{ >{\tiny} p{18em}|p{1em}|p{1em}lp{1em}lp{1em}lp{1em}lp{1em}ll|llllllll|llllll|}
                        \centering
                        \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{3.8cm}{\textbf{Author and year of publication (chronologically)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{1cm}{\textbf{Number of datasets}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{1cm}{\textbf{Year of dataset}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-8}[-8]{*}{\parbox{1cm}{\textbf{Monitoring period (year=y, month=m, week=w, day=d)}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Monitoring place}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{.5cm}{\textbf{Obser\-vations}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\parbox{.5cm}{\textbf{Vari\-ables}}}} & \multicolumn{6}{p{\widthof{GB}+\widthof{GD}+\widthof{MAE}+\widthof{MAPE}+\widthof{MASE}+\widthof{MRE}+\widthof{MSE}}}{\centering\textbf{Evaluation metrics}} & \multicolumn{4}{r|}{}         & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\parbox{4cm}{\textbf{Thematic clusters}}} \\
                        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{GB}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{GD}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2em}}{\parbox{.25cm}{\textbf{MAE}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2em}}{\parbox{.25cm}{\textbf{MAPE}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2em}}{\parbox{.25cm}{\textbf{MASE}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2em}}{\parbox{.25cm}{\textbf{MRE}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\parbox{.25cm}{\textbf{MSE}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{RMSE}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1em}|}{\parbox{0.2cm}{\textbf{$\sigma$}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{W/E}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{TE}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{HB}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{EF}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{\textbf{SocDem}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}|}{\textbf{BT}} \\
                        \midrule
                        Hawarah, Ploix \& Jacomino (2010) & 1     &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.22em}}{1y} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.665em}}{France} &       & 7     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} &       &       &  \\
                        Basu et al. (2011) & 1     &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.22em}}{1y} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.665em}}{France} &       & 10    &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} &       &       &       &  \\
                        Kandananond (2011) & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{1986–2010} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.22em}}{25y} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.665em}}{Thailand} &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X} &       &  \\
\bottomrule
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{longtable}%
                    \label{tab:addlabel}%
            \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could start by reducing the width of the first column in order to save some space. What's the purpose of all the repeated `\multicolumn{1}{p{4.055em}}{X}`? Wouldn't a simple `X` be sufficient here?

Comment: That does decrease the unnecessary space a little bit, but still leaves large unnecessary gaps in columns (like between columns 10 and 11 or 11 and 12).

Comment: Also think about your readers, do anyone wany to read such a huge table potentially scaled down to a super small font size. You can probably do a lot to help the readability by using a better design, better column headers and by using table notes.

Comment: I was thinking about that, too. Unfortunately these are my Faculty’s requirements (include all literature, analytical methods, and evaluation tools used in a single table. Thus, I can’t really decrease the number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

the markup used was very over complicated (you never need to nest a parbox in a p column and apart from the headings you do not need parbox line breaking here at all. this fits although I may have missed some vertical lines and alignments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=openany,numbers=noenddot,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm,marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon,font={footnotesize,sf},labelfont={footnotesize,sf}]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{cont}{#1~#2\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelsep=period,labelformat=cont}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
                \tiny
                \singlespacing
               \setlength\LTleft{-1.5cm plus 1fill}
               \setlength\LTright{-1.5cm plus 1fill}
                \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
                % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table_1'
                \begin{longtable}{@{}p{18em}|l|lllllllllll|llllllll|llllll|@{}}
                \bfseries\thead{Author and year\\ of publication\\ (chronologically)} &
 \bfseries\thead{Number\\ of\\ datasets} &
\bfseries\thead{Year\\ of\\ dataset} &
\bfseries\thead{Monit-\\oring\\ period} &
\bfseries\thead{Monit-\\oring\\ place} & 
\bfseries\thead{Obser-\\vations} &
\bfseries\thead{Vari-\\ables} &
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries\thead{Evaluation metrics}} &
 \multicolumn{4}{r|}{}         &
 \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\bfseries\thead{Thematic clusters}}\\
                        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       & \textbf{GB} & \textbf{GD} & \textbf{MAE} & \textbf{MAPE} & \textbf{MASE} & \textbf{MRE} & \textbf{MSE} & \textbf{RMSE} & \textbf{AUC} & \boldmath$\sigma$ & \textbf{W/E} & \textbf{TE} & \textbf{HB} & \textbf{EF} & \textbf{SocDem} & \textbf{BT}\\
                        \midrule
                        Hawarah, Ploix \& Jacomino (2010) & 1     &       & 1y & France &       & 7     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &       &  \\
                        Basu et al. (2011) & 1     &       & 1y & France &       & 10    &       & X &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X & X &       &       &       &  \\
                        Kandananond (2011) & 1     & 1986–2010 & 25y & Thailand &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &  \\
\bottomrule
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{longtable}%
                    \label{tab:addlabel}%
            \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=openany,numbers=noenddot,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm,marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon,font={footnotesize,sf},labelfont={footnotesize,sf}]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{cont}{#1~#2\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelsep=period,labelformat=cont}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccrlrr*{17}{c}@{}}
  \caption{caption on the first page}
  \label{tab:key}\\
  \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Author\\ \& year\textsuperscript{a)}}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{No. of\\ datasets}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Year of\\ dataset}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Monitoring}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Obser-\\ vations}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Vari-\\ ables}} 
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Evaluation metrics}} 
    & & & &        
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Thematic clusters}} 
\\
\cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{8-13} \cmidrule{18-24}
    &  &  &  \thead{period\textsuperscript{b)}}   &  \thead{place}  &  & 
    & \thead{GB}   & \thead{GD}       & \thead{MAE}    & \thead{MAPE} 
    & \thead{MASE} & \thead{MRE}      & \thead{MSE}    & \thead{RMSE} 
    & \thead{AUC}  & \thead{$\sigma$} & \thead{W/E}    & \thead{TE} 
    & \thead{HB}   & \thead{EF}       & \thead{SocDem} & \thead{BT} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{caption on the following pages}\\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Author\\ \& year\textsuperscript{a)}}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{No. of\\ datasets}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Year of\\ dataset}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Monitoring}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Obser-\\ vations}} 
    & \multirow{2.25}{*}{\thead{Vari-\\ ables}} 
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Evaluation metrics}} 
    & & & &        
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Thematic clusters}} 
\\
\cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{8-13} \cmidrule{18-24}
    &  &  &  \thead{period\textsuperscript{b)}}   &  \thead{place}  &  & 
    & \thead{GB}   & \thead{GD}       & \thead{MAE}    & \thead{MAPE} 
    & \thead{MASE} & \thead{MRE}      & \thead{MSE}    & \thead{RMSE} 
    & \thead{AUC}  & \thead{$\sigma$} & \thead{W/E}    & \thead{TE} 
    & \thead{HB}   & \thead{EF}       & \thead{SocDem} & \thead{BT} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{24}{l}{\textsuperscript{a)} sorted chronologically by publication year, \textsuperscript{b)} year=y, month=m, week=w, day=d}\\
\endfoot
   Hawarah, Ploix \& Jacomino (2010) & 1     &       & 1 y & France &       & 7     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &       &  \\ \addlinespace
  Basu et al. (2011) & 1     &       & 1 y & France &       & 10    &       & X &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X & X &       &       &       &  \\ \addlinespace
  Kandananond (2011) & 1     & 1986–2010 & 25 y & Thailand &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & X &       &  \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```